# nginx sites available not loading correct domain

Tags: nginx

I have several domains working fine on an nginx. I'm trying to add another one now, but it keeps bringing up another domain.

This is one of the sites available config files, the on that always loads when trying to enter the new domain.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name   www.domain1.com;
    return       301 http://domain1.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen   80;

    root /data/domain1.com/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain1.com;

    error_log /data/domain1.com/logs/error.log error;
    access_log /data/domain1.com/logs/access.log;



    location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

}
```

And this is the one I'm using for the new one:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name   www.domain2.com;
    return       301 http://domain2.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen   80;

    root /data/domain2.com/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain2.com *.domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    error_log /data/domain2.com/logs/error.log error;
    access_log /data/domain2.com/logs/access.log;



    location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

}
```

If I remove the first file, the new domain loads fine.

Comment: You have two server blocks with `www.domain2.com` in the `server_name`. You mention *sites available*, but you know `nginx` is often configured to load its files from *sites enabled*?

Comment: Both `fastcgi_pass`-directives point to the same backend. Are you sure that your backend actually handles the different domain names, i.e. shows different content based on the domain?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yep, the symlink is there and working, because when I take the older file it loads perfectly even though there ar other 5 domains running.

Comment: @Digitalkapitaen Yes, it already handles 5 other domains without problem.